# Insert into list an element at specific index, overwrite the element at same index or expanding list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've got a list that looks like:

```
a_list = ['A','B','C','D']
```

And I want to achieve something like (able to expand the list):

```
new_index = 6
new_value = 'AA'
a_list = insert_value(new_index, new_value)
print(a_list)
#['A','B','C','D','','','AA']
```

And also something like (able to over-write the new_value):

```
new_index = 2
new_value = 'AA'
a_list = insert_value(new_index, new_value)
print(a_list)
#['A','B','AA','D']
```

Comment: overwrite any existing element by doing `a_list[index]=value`

Comment: So many options. `list.append()` adds to the end, `list.insert()` does what you would expect. There's also indexing. Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
def expand_insert(lst, idx, ele):
    if len(lst) < idx:
        void = idx - len(lst)

        for i in range(void):
            lst.append("")
        lst.append(ele)
    else:
        lst[idx] = ele
    return lst

print(expand_insert(a_list, 6, "AA"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a_list = ['A','B','C','D']
index = [6,2]

for i in index:
if i >= len(a_list):
    a_list.extend([''] * (i - len(a_list) + 1))
    print(a_list)
    a_list[i] = 'BBB'
else:
    a_list[i] = 'AAA'

a_list
['A', 'B', 'AAA', 'D', '', '', 'BBB']
```